# Definition of limit superior of real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a problem relating the following two definitions.

*$\overline{\textrm{lim}} \ x_n = \inf_n \sup_{k\geq n} x_k$*

and

*A real number $\ell$ is the limit superior of the sequence $<x_n>$ iff (i) given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists n$ s.t. $x_k<\ell + \epsilon$ for all $k\geq n$ and (ii) given $\epsilon>0$ and $n$, $\exists k\geq n$ s.t. $x_k>\ell - \epsilon$.*

My understanding of limit superior is that it is the infimum of the set of all superimums of $x_k$'s subsequences. On the other hand, what I understand from the second definition is that $\ell$ is a lim. superior if (i) there exists a subsequence that is upperbounded by $\ell$ and (ii) (This is the part that I don't quite get) for each subsequence there is a 'subsubsequence' lower-bounded by $\ell$.

Can you help me out with this?